# Call a function from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When the form is submitted, its gets handles by JavaScript. From the JavaScript, I' am looping the **[serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)** for the hidden field called "**action**".

```
/* This is the funtion that handles the action from .ajax-about form */
function ajax_about_birthday(dataArray){
    alert("Works!");
}

$("#about-form-horizontal .ajax-about").submit(function(){
    var form, dataArray, action;
    form = $(this).serializeArray();
    dataArray = form, dataObj = {};
    $(dataArray).each(function(i, field){
        dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
    }); 
    action = dataObj['action'];
    action(); // I' am stuck here, how will I call the function using the value from action variable
});
```

From the above code, I don't get any error on the Console.

Comment: If your function is defined in global scope you can use `window[action]()`

Comment: what is wrong with `dataObj['action']()` ?

Comment: @Mr_Green That it won't work? `dataObj['action']` is a string.

Comment: is value of 'action' field in html form function of its string name?

Comment: @JJRoman It can't be a function, because it comes from `serializeArray()` which is a key = element name, value = element value, which is always a string.

Comment: @dfsq If it is not and object, then the only option is eval?

Comment: @JJRoman In global context `window[action]()`. Or if functions are in some other object `actions[action]()`. Otherwise `eval` or `new Function`.